# esp8266-12e Nodemcu 1.0 board not starting uploaded data sketch from Arduino IDE

Tags: c++, arduino-ide, esp8266, nodemcu, firmware

I've uploaded a sketch from the Arduino IDE to my (Amica) esp8266-12e board with the sketch data upload tool (ESP8266FS). This goes without any errors or problems. However, the code is never executed, it's like that the code isn't even on the board, it does nothing. I've tried flashing the firmware several times but this does not help. Depending on the installed firmware I get different messages on the serial monitor such as

```
NodeMCU 0.9.5 build 20150318  powered by Lua 5.1.4
lua: cannot open init.lua
```

or

```
Ai-Thinker Technology Co.,Ltd.
invalid
```

So installing different kinds of firmware is not the problem here. What did I do wrong which causes the board to 'ignore' the uploaded data sketch?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have not uploaded the Arduino Core Software to your ESP8266 device because you are getting messages from the LUA interpreter which is overwritten when you install the Arduino Core Software. 
The pre-requisites for using ESP8266FS to load sketches are here: [ESP8266FS](https://github.com/esp8266/arduino-esp8266fs-plugin)